# Ignite-web agent pod is not spin even after successful create command

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I am deploying web agent via web-agent-deployment.yaml. So I ran the below command

```
root@ip-10-11.x.x.:~/ignite# kubectl create -f web-agent-deployment.yaml
```

deployment `web-agent` created

But still no web-agent pod spin at all. Please check below command output.

```
root@ip-10-10-11.x.x:~/ignite# kubectl get pods -n ignite

NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ignite-cluster-6qhmf   1/1       Running   0          2h
ignite-cluster-lpgrt   1/1       Running   0          2h
```

as per official Doc, it should come Like blow.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n ignite

  NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  web-agent-5596bd78c-h4272   1/1       Running   0          1h
```

This is my web-agent file:-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-agent
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-agent
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-agent
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ignite-cluster
      containers:
      - name: web-agent
        image: apacheignite/web-agent
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500Mi
        env:
        - name: DRIVER_FOLDER
          value: "./jdbc-drivers"
        - name: NODE_URI
          value: ""https://10.11.X.Y:8080"" #my One of worker Node IP
        - name: SERVER_URI
          value: "http://frontend.web-console.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: TOKENS
          value: ""
        - name: NODE_LOGIN
          value: web-agent
        - name: NODE_PASSWORD
          value: password
```

Comment: Hi, can you run `kubectl get deployment --all-namespaces`

Comment: You're looking at the pods that are supposedly created by the Deployment. Look for the Deployment instead: `kubectl describe deployment web-agent -n ignite`. Tried  on my end and pods kept crashed due to multiple reasons (first being, no service account was created). Check what's yours in the *status* section.

Comment: output :- Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  Available        False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
  Progressing      False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:    <none>
NewReplicaSet:     web-agent-6497bcd484 (0/1 replicas created)
Events:            <none>

Comment: Fixed, Need to create a related "service".